# iPhone app crashs after some months

Tags: iphone, swift, memory, crash

I wrote a small swift game with 80 - 120 MB of RAM requirement. It runs fine on the simulator. Then I transfered it to the iPhone (4s) and it run fine too. After some month it crashed while initializing. I could remove it from memory and restart it entirely, but the problem remained.

Because I didn't change anything to the iPhone, the iOS version is still the same, I think it is a memory issue?
But when I copy it again from the Dev Mac to the iPhone, it runs again fine. So memory is not realy lost meanwhile. What could be the reason? What did change over time?

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: No, the app is on my wife's iPhone. I don't have installed any log functions. Could I get it without setting something special for this app?

Answer (score 2):

Provisioning profiles become invalid after some time, if you don't have a paid developer account, that time is 3 months after you create the provisioning profile for the device. The codesigning will then be invalid and iOS won't let you run that app. Reinstalling the game to the phone should solve the problem although Xcode may say "Code signing is invalid" and give a compiler error. Just click "Fix Issue" and Xcode will take care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution.